# Using RVM via bash script

Tags: ruby, bash, rvm, ruby-2.3

I wanted to write a small bash script to automatically setup the correct ruby version and gemset for a new project. For testing I have `rvm` installed with ruby `2.3.1` and two gemsets: `foo` and `bar`.

Even a simple test like this doesn't return what expected:

```
$ rvm current
ruby-2.3.1@foo

$ ./script
Using ruby-2.3.1 with gemset bar
Using /(...)/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1 with gemset bar
ruby-2.3.1@bar

$ rvm current
ruby-2.3.1@foo
```

Contents of the script:

```
#!/bin/bash --login
rvm gemset use bar
rvm use 2.3.1@bar
rvm current
```

Other operations like installing rubies or creating gemsets seem to work, I just can't get `use` to modify the current version used by the script caller. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was obviously simple, I should have called the script using

```
. ./script
```